# Jira JQL construct string for searching

Tags: jira, jql

Is it possible to construct string that you are going to search by?
Example is `fixVersion` are set as dates, so `fix202005` for May of 2020, or `fix202004`, these sometimes get postponed so we update the `fixVersion` thus searching by date created or such events is not possible with current way of things, so ideal solution for me is to create filter for `previous`, `current`, `following`.

Mock example(non-working):

```
fixVersion = "fix$(currentYear())$(currentMonth(-1))" AND issueType = Task
fixVersion = "fix$(currentYear())$(currentMonth())" AND issueType = Task
fixVersion = "fix$(currentYear())$(currentMonth(+1))" AND issueType = Task
```

Is something like this possible with JQL? Any other method to achieve same would be greatly appreciated.